# Python steam webscraping with bs4 value returned as none

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I logged into my steam account and try to get the money amount of my steam wallet but the value is always none plz help.

```py
import webbrowser, requests, time, datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def get_bal():
    bal = requests.get('https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=730&q=dragon')
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(bal.content, "html.parser")
    money = soup2.find(id="marketWalletBalanceAmount")
    #money = 4.8
    print(money)
    return money
get_bal()
```

Comment: On going to the link that you have shared, I go to the page source and do not find any id called ```marketWalletBalanceAmount```. Is it something that you find in the source only when you are logged in? In that case, the easiest way would be to first log in and then run this script on that session.

Comment: Didn't see setting cookies for `request`. Within cookie there can be identifier(s) by which the server can recognize that you are the logged in guy. This is one of the problems. Are you new to networking? Meow...

Comment: @TrumpHellothere we can't log into you steam account so we can't see what you see when you go to that url... I would suggest you add some screen shots of the page you are trying to scrape along with your browser's inspector focused on the element of interest (here price..)...

Comment: Also I would also suggest looking into selenium... most websites today are dynamic and can't easily be scrapped with just bs4..